# watir is unable to find autopopulated div element

Tags: html, ruby, watir

Below is the element after typing "Abernathy and Sons" text in text field to generate auto-populated list

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10"> ==$0
    "Abernathy and Sons "
    <p>
        <i class="fa fa-map-maker"></i>
            " atlanta, GA"
    </p>
```

I have tried with the element

```
{browser.div(text: "Abernathy and Sons ")}
```

Giving error:

> timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #/"Abernathy and Sons "/, :tag_name=>"div"}> to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is,

```
b.div(text: "someText")
```

Will form the xpath as follows in selenium

```
driver.find_element(xpath: "//div[normalize-space(.)='someText']")
```

So `normalize-space()` method in xpath will compare the string after removing the trailing and leading space. So if you add a space after or before the string then it will throw the error unable to find element. So If I write the blow code then you will have the same error you are getting.

```
b.div(text: "someText ") #look at the space after someText.
```

So remove the space before and after the string it will work perfectly.

Comment: Added space for the text and every time am giving different text in the search box...
Can you please give the perfect element in watir

Comment: while doing browser.find_element(xpath: "//div[normalize-space(.)='someText']")
throwing error:  undefined method `find_element' for #<Watir::Browser:0x000000072981d0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: I am not asking you to write selenium code. Watir automatically converts your code into selenium code. You write watir code without any space. For an instance,  write this code, it would work. I removed the space so use this one.  `browser.div(text: "Abernathy and Sons")`

Comment: Resolved the issue with xpath contains text... thanks for your valuable suggestions

Comment: Accept the answer. There is a hollow tic at the top left side of my answer which you have to click, upon your click, it will change its colour into green.